# Relation between compact ,open and closure

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have this part of a proof:

$x\in W_x\subset K_x\cap U_x$ where $W_x$ is open and $K_x$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$  and $U_x$ an open neighborhood of $x$.

As $A=K_x\setminus W_x$ is compact there exists two open sets $U,V$ such that $x\in V\subset W_x, A\subset U$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

So $\overline{V}\cap U=\emptyset$ and $\overline{V}\subset K_x$

I don't understand why $\overline{V}\cap U=\emptyset $ and $\overline{V}\subset K_x$????

Please help me

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is $z\in \overline V\cap U$, then $U$ is an open nbhd of $z\in\overline V$, hence must meet $V$: $V\cap U\ne\varnothing$. On the other hand, $V\subset W_x\subset K_x$. I guess we deal with Hausdorff topologies, hence $K_x$, being compact, is closed, hence $\overline V\subset K_x$.

Comment: yes yes yes thank you

Comment: please can you told me why $\overline{V}\subset K_x$ ? thank you

Comment: I'v edited my answer.